# Boolean expression using Spring Profiles

Tags: java, spring

We have the following annotation for a Component in a project:

```
@Profile("!department")
```

This means run this component when department is not an active profile.
However, can you do something like:

`@Profile("!department" || "datamigration" )` OR

```
 @Profile(["!department","datamigration"] )
```

Basically I want a way to be able to say, use this `Component` if:

- profile is NOT department

  - OR
- profile is datamigration

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be enough

```
@Profile({"!department","datamigration"})
```